# test list of dynamically created table headers using protractor and angular 6

Tags: protractor, angular6, e2e-testing

I am using protractor with angular 6. stuck in a situation where i want to write test case to test a list of table headers which are created with data coming from backend called in ngOnInit.

i tried using tick and fakeAsync but keep on getting error

> Failed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of null

below is my code:

**app.po.ts**

```
goToScannersList() {
    return browser.get('/scanners');
  }
getScannersList() {

        let items = element.all(by.css('.scannerlist th')).map(function (elm) {
          return elm.getText();
        });
        return items;

      }
```

If i use spec like in 1) i get error mentioned above even if i remove page.goToScannersList();
but if use spec like in 2) my test is success irrespective of what value it returns.

1)
**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
it('should display list of scanners', fakeAsync(() => {
    page.goToScannersList();
    tick(4000);
    expect(page.getScannersList()).toEqual([
      "ScannerID",
      "Desc",
      "Owner"
    ]);

    }));
```

2)
**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
it('should display list of scanners', () => {
    page.goToScannersList();
    fakeAsync(()=>{
    tick(4000);
    expect(page.getScannersList()).toEqual([
      "ScannerID",
      "Desc",
      "Owner"
    ]);
 })
    });
```

**scanners.component.html**

```
<table class="scannerlist" id="scannersList" style="text-align:center;width:100%">
<thead>
  <tr ><th *ngFor="let col of scannerKeys">{{col}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of scannerData">
    <td>{{row.ScannerID}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Desc}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Owner}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**scanners.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.scannerService.getScannerDetails().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.scannerData = data.Data;
      this.scannerKeys = this.getKeys(data.Data[0]);
    });

  }
```

let me know if anybody has any idea how to implement it. thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The error does not like from `page.getScannersList()`, please check it comes from `page.goToScannersList()`?

Comment: thats correct, i moved the navigation out of fakeAsync function and it worked. but why is it that we cant do navigation inside fakeAsync. or to put in other words should i test navigation in separate test case. any example would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: i am still getting the error, can someone help please? i have edited the question with two scenerios of test spec.